Meta Ad Library API permission error (subcode 2332004)
I'm creating a datacollector which would fetch data from public available ad in order to retrieve it on my app.
Basically, I would like to create a copycat of the official tool from Meta on my application.
I followed the Meta Ad Library API Guide, generated the user token access and when I make a call (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/ads_archive?ad_reached_countries=["FR"]&search_terms=savon&access_token=MY_TOKEN) I always have this return :
{
"error": {
    "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "error_subcode": 2332004,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "App role required",
    "error_user_msg": "You need to be assigned a role by the app owner to continue. Learn more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles",
    "fbtrace_id": "AEtWDzYFQypjN8PvUhnHwSQ"
}

I've seen many issues identical to mine (another one here) and I don't really understand as my user is an administrator, of a fully verified business.
I even found people saying it's because the app doesn't have the correct scopes (such as : ads_read, public_profile). I can't add the scope "ads_archive" on my app as I can't see it anywhere in App Review > Permissions and Features on my developer account, otherwise everything seems okay, here is the debug of my token :
{
"data": {
    "app_id": "APP_ID",
    "type": "USER",
    "application": "APPLICATION_NAME",
    "data_access_expires_at": 1734880167,
    "expires_at": 1727107200,
    "is_valid": true,
    "scopes": [
        "read_insights",
        "pages_show_list",
        "ads_management",
        "ads_read",
        "business_management",
        "pages_read_engagement",
        "pages_read_user_content",
        "public_profile"
    ],
    "granular_scopes": [
        {
            "scope": "pages_show_list"
        },
        {
            "scope": "ads_management"
        },
        {
            "scope": "ads_read"
        },
        {
            "scope": "business_management"
        },
        {
            "scope": "pages_read_engagement"
        },
        {
            "scope": "pages_read_user_content"
        }
    ],
    "user_id": "USER_ID"
}

}
How to finally access the public data ?
